# binance smart chain testnet verify not working at all

Tags: ethereum, solidity, remix, binance-smart-chain, etherscan

even this simple smart contract is not verifing in the binance testnet platform
I can not find the issue.
already tried with and without constructor parameters.
I complied it using remix.

**smart contract**

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract miniContract {
    address contractCreator;
  

    constructor() public {
        contractCreator = msg.sender;
        
    }
 

}
```

**ABI Code**

```
[
    {
        "inputs": [],
        "stateMutability": "nonpayable",
        "type": "constructor"
    }
]
```

**ByteCode**

```
6080604052348015600f57600080fd5b50336000806101000a81548173ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff021916908373ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff160217905550603f80605d6000396000f3fe6080604052600080fdfea2646970667358221220fbeaad32f4b33eaa4eaf624c2ff32432ae611a5adbe9a4da1709388a3e65ba5464736f6c63430008120033
```

[verify page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86Td1.png)

thanks a lot

I tried with and without constructor parameters.
I tried minify abiCode

Answer (score 2):

Since your constructor doesn't accept any arguments, leave the "Constructor Arguments" field on BscScan empty.

---

If your constructor accepted any arguments, you'd need to pass the ABI-encoded values - not the ABI JSON definition of the constructor function (what you're doing now).

For example: `uint256` type, decimal value `1000` is encoded as `0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000003E8`

---

> *I tried with and without constructor parameters.*

Assuming you've selected the same compiler version, optimization params, and other inputs that you used to compile your code, it will work with the "Constructor Arguments" field empty. If the form returns a different error message that you're not able to resolve, please submit a separate question with steps to reproduce the other issue.